# VF page to PDF to Notes & Attachments

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two VF pages and a class, which is shown below.
When Decision Status is Accepted, a visualforce page is generated but now I wanted to convert this VF page to PDF and save it notes and attachments. So  created another VF page "DecisionLetter_V2" and include the first VF page "DecisionLetter". Name of the file generated is DecisionLetter.Systen.Now() as shown in the class and same file is generated 5 times.

**MY CODE BELOW**

**VF Page: (DecisionLetter)-- Data is on this page**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="TargetX_SRMb__Application__c"
extensions="attachPDFToContact" action="{!attachPDF}"
standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false"
applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" lightningstylesheets="true">
```

---

**VF Page: (DecisionLetter_V2)**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
<apex:include pageName="DecisionLetter"/>
</apex:page>
```

---

**Class:**

```
public class attachPDFToContact {
public string recId {set;get;}

//constructor
public attachPDFToContact(ApexPages.StandardController standardPageController) {
    recId = standardPageController.getId();
}

//method called from the Visualforce's action attribute
public void attachPDF() {
    Blob pdfBlob;
    try {
    PageReference pdfPage = Page.DecisionLetter_v2;
    pdfPage.getParameters().put('id',recId);
    pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContent();
           }catch(exception e){
        pdfBlob = blob.valueOf('this is from excetion  '+e.getMessage());
    }
    Attachment attach = new Attachment(ParentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'), Name = 'DecisionLetter - '+ system.Now() + '.pdf', body = pdfBlob);
    insert attach;
  }
```

}

Comment: please edit your post to clarify.  Are the attachments all the same size and name?  How many does it create and is it consistently the same?  How are you invoking the VF page?

Comment: I am calling the class from VF page "DecisionLetter" using action button. I don't want to create multiple files, I just want one file to be created when I open the letter by going to the contact object and login to the community as a user but currently its creating 5 pdf files under notes and attachments.